# OpenID2.0 Google log in issue?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I use Google account and recently started seeing [OpenID 2.0 issue](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6206245?p=openid&rd=1) when I try logging on. Is there a plan to reactivate Google account (Google+ should work)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8857/openid2.0-google-log-in-issue?/) by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[gazebo answers signin](http://answers.gazebosim.org/account/signin/?next=/)

and click on "recover your account via email"

---

Originally posted by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) with karma: 80 on 2015-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on 2015-06-09**:
With your suggestion, `OpenID 2.0` issue still remains but I was able to login with my Google account.